# alternative implementation of pipe() using read/write into file

Tags: linux, pipe

I have an alternative implementation of `pipe()` in Linux:

```
int pipe(int pipefd[2]) {
    char *name = unique_name();
    pipefd[1] = open(name, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0600);
    pipefd[0] = open(name, O_RDONLY, 0600);
    unlink(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Does this implementation is legal alternative for `pipe()` like in the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)? If no, why?

Answer (score 0):

This implementation is wrong because reading from the pipe should return 0 instead of blocking.

By the semantic of pipe(), when reading before that something is written, the process is blocked and wait for data. In this implementation, reading before writing return 0 (EOF).